# Do we need to completely reform our mod team?

Tags: discussion

What is this nonsense of Gayot Fow banned? He is, by a mile, our biggest asset. If our moderators can't work with him, we need new moderators.

Comment: To keep this constructive, I suggest focusing on *actions,* not *users.* Ad hominem attacks never go well, so likewise, claiming that a suspension(?)  should NOT be allowed because of who they are (rather than what they *did*) will be equally ineffective.

Comment: @no more answers w these mods: No matter what happened and who was right in the first place - your approach will not help anybody. You cannot win this war.

Answer (score 25):

There's nothing stopping Gayot Fow from returning to the site except for Gayot Fow. Having interacted with him in chat on at least one prior occasion, I'm not entirely surprised that he's stamping his foot about getting a slap on the wrist, but that's something he'll have to work out for himself (or not, as the case may be). In short, his absence is no-one's business but his own and neither you nor I nor the moderator team here can do a damn thing about it.

Replacing an entire moderation team is a massive undertaking, *particularly* for a site with years of history where the current team's experience would be sorely missed; if additional moderators are needed (either to augment the current team's experience or coverage or to replace a moderator who is stepping down) then we'll run an election for one or two new positions... But given the fact that [y'all *just* picked two new mods this past spring](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/3) I don't see that being particularly urgent.

We're certainly not going to throw the entire site into chaos because you or anyone else thinks they have the right to hold it hostage. So change your name, stamp your foot or leave the site entirely... Being petty won't make one bit of difference apart from demonstrating your ability to be, well, petty.

Comment: And one of those mods were a mistake; and the rest are simply guilty of not stopping him. And so the official stance of SE is that if a moderator doesn't work out is to do nothing and if someone takes a stand against him then he is petty? Interesting.

Comment: The official stance of SE is that anyone who feels they were suspended unfairly can bring the matter up for discussion with the moderator *team* (publicly or privately), the community as a whole (here on meta), or the SE team (privately as provided by the "contact" link at the bottom of most every page). We cannot recommend that discussion be carried out via 3rd-parties or via an off-site blog. Remember that the moderator team was elected to serve the entire community here; accusations of malfeasance against one should thus be brought before either the electorate or their representatives.

Answer (score 23):

User Gayot Fow has never been banned from the main site. One month ago he was suspended from chat for 72 hours after receiving several warnings regarding the breaking of chat rules, however that ban has long expired.

Gayot Fow is more than welcome to come back and I have in fact personally encouraged him to do so through his blog. Other mods also welcome his generous contributions and vast knowledge base.

Comment: So we *do* need a new mod team, you can't ban someone like him, if there's a conflict, automatically ban the other party. This is just common sense.

Comment: @chx if you believe the mod team has erred feel free to escalate this matter to the site administration.

Comment: @chx - I hear you saying that some people are above the law.